# Unable to install Spanish DNIe on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, firefox

I'm trying to install the spanish DNIe on Ubuntu 22.04 using the official government-site downloads. The package to intall is libpkcs11-dnie_1.6.8_amd64.deb and I installed it using sudo from the command line.

I'm on Firefox 106.0.5 and I'm using a ChipNet iBox Plus card reader.  I've used the pcsc tools to check the card reader and it's fine.

I first checked it was there by running lsusb, the used to pcsc_scan tool (i had to start the service manually with "service pcscd start" first). It detects the card and then reads with DNI card when it's inserted. So that's all working.

The problem is loading the .so file that supports the hardware in Firefox. I've downloaded the package from the official government site and it seems to install OK but the date on the .so file which is in /usr/lib is over a year old. I can't find a more recent module file with a later installation date.

Trying to identify the .so module file with the card reader through the Firefox settings froze it several times, looking for some script file by the look of things. No trace of that file anywhere.

I checked to see if the libpkcs11-dnie.so file was loaded and being accessed using the command:
lsof /usr/lib/libpkcs11-dnie.so
and I found a process using it, in my case with PID 1717.

To find out if the .so file was opened, I used:
lsof -p 1717 | grep .so and it was opened. So some process was clearly using the file.

I've also purged and reinstalled the packages.

I've also tried leaving messages in Spanish on the tech support sites but that went into a black hole.

SO now I've run out of things to check. It looks like the package is buggy unless someone can suggest other things to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just fyi, those DNIe packages, to use a mobile as a NFC reader or a smartcard reader need openssl 1.1 to be present. Ubuntu 22.04 does not ship it but openssl 3. I downloaded its sources and installed it manually from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz . After that I copied libcrypto.so.1.1 and libssl.so.1.1 to /usr/lib .